# Can't connect google cloud sql from mac terminal

Tags: google-cloud-sql, ipv4

I added my IPv4 to the white list networks but trying to access mysql instance returns time out error,
With the same configuration when I try to connect it from DbVisualizer https://www.dbvis.com/ it connects.
any ideas?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue ? If so, would you post the solution please, as to benefit the community encountering a similar issue?

Comment: No I couldn't I used another free mysql server mysql6.gear.host